# How to do git merge/pull correctly: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists)

Tags: git, merge, git-pull

I am a newbie to Git and having trouble understanding how to use Git. I have been using CVS so going through some learning curve for Git. Here is what all I tried

Now I had changed only two files PromoServiceImpl.java and build.sql. However having trouble merging changed from "product" branch.

Remaining files that you see (like ApiServiceImpl.java etc) are changes from other users but I am not sure if the representation here suggests that I have changed them. Prob it got merged during earlier pull commands and now it expects me to commit them ??

No matter whatever is the flow of commands I follow (even after some Google search) I see the following error:

> You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists)
>   Please, commit your changes before you can merge.

Here is the sequence of commands I followed and output (tried to make it pretty by inserting new lines for everyone to read). Also this error comes back even after taking changes from repository afresh so I am sure I am doing something wrong rather than some issue with git.

```sh
kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/promo/impl/PromoServiceImpl.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git pull origin product
From ssh://192.168.2.251/TryGit
 * branch            product    -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging TryGitResources/build/build.sql
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in TryGitResources/build/build.sql
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   TryGitCore/src/main/java/com/TryGit/core/api/binding.xml
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/api/impl/ApiServiceImpl.java
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/common/impl/StartupServiceImpl.java
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/TryGit.wsdl
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/homeDeal.css
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/TryGit.css
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/img/TryGit/sprite/TryGit.png
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/createPromoCode.jsp
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/product/productAdmin.jsp
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/deal/homePage.jsp

#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      TryGitResources/build/build.sql
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/promo/impl/PromoServiceImpl.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git reset TryGitResources/build/build.sql
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   TryGitResources/build/build.sql
M   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/promo/impl/PromoServiceImpl.java
kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   TryGitCore/src/main/java/com/TryGit/core/api/binding.xml
#   modified:   TryGitResources/build/build.sql
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/api/impl/ApiServiceImpl.java
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/common/impl/StartupServiceImpl.java
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/TryGit.wsdl
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/homeDeal.css
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/TryGit.css
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/img/TryGit/sprite/TryGit.png
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/createPromoCode.jsp
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/product/productAdmin.jsp
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/deal/homePage.jsp
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   TryGitResources/build/build.sql
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/promo/impl/PromoServiceImpl.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on product: b8bb080 changing build.sql for RBT task
HEAD is now at b8bb080 changing build.sql for RBT task


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git reset Adding


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git reset Adding


kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git rm Adding
fatal: pathspec 'Adding' did not match any files

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ man git rm

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git rm Adding
fatal: pathspec 'Adding' did not match any files

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git pull origin product
remote: Counting objects: 566, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (316/316), done.
remote: Total 386 (delta 207), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (386/386), 203.81 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (207/207), completed with 56 local objects.
From ssh://192.168.2.251/TryGit
 * branch            product    -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging TryGitResources/build/build.sql
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in TryGitResources/build/build.sql
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git pull origin product
M   TryGitCore/src/main/java/com/TryGit/core/api/binding.xml
U   TryGitResources/build/build.sql
M   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/api/impl/ApiServiceImpl.java
M   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/common/impl/StartupServiceImpl.java
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/TryGit.wsdl
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/homeDeal.css
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/TryGit.css
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/img/TryGit/sprite/TryGit.png
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/createPromoCode.jsp
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/product/productAdmin.jsp
M   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/deal/homePage.jsp
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git add TryGitResources/build/build.sql
kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git pull origin product
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ gs
# On branch product
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/product' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   TryGitCore/src/main/java/com/TryGit/core/api/binding.xml
#   modified:   TryGitResources/build/build.sql
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/api/impl/ApiServiceImpl.java
#   modified:   TryGitServices/src/main/java/com/TryGit/services/common/impl/StartupServiceImpl.java
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/TryGit.wsdl
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/homeDeal.css
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/css/TryGit/TryGit.css
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/static/img/TryGit/sprite/TryGit.png
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/createPromoCode.jsp
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/admin/product/productAdmin.jsp
#   modified:   TryGitWeb/src/main/webapp/views/deal/homePage.jsp

#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git pull origin product
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.

kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$
```

Comment: A quick advice: just forget about 'git pull'. You don't need it, and it's the best way to get lost in git. Since it's merely a git fetch followed by a merge, use both of these! And inbetween, you may (certainly!) want to have a look at what you're actually going to merge. You may also want to rebase instead of merge. In my opinion, git pull is a shortcut which can be very confusing.

Comment: @François i would be very careful with rebase - it changes history, which shouldn't be done in terms of VCS, because that's what it's for - to preserve history.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.  It helps to understand what happens when you issue various Git commands.

The `pull` command (as in `git pull`) [results in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.  So when you did a `pull`

```
kamal@kamal-Lenovo-G470:~/git/TryGit$ git pull origin product
```

Git tried to pull in changes from the default remote repository

```
From ssh://192.168.2.251/TryGit
 * branch            product    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and merge them in.

```
Auto-merging TryGitResources/build/build.sql
```

In so doing it encountered a conflict

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in TryGitResources/build/build.sql
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

[Git maintains this 3 versions](http://book.git-scm.com/5_advanced_branching_and_merging.html) of the file pending a merge -- *your* changes, changes pulled in and the common ancestor.  The version pulled in is temporarily stored in MERGE_HEAD.

You can see the differences with a `git diff` invocation.  At this point you need to fix the conflicts that Git was unable to automatically resolve.   Once you have fixed it simply perform the usual `git add` followed by a `git commit`.  This process is also explained in the examples section of the man page for the `commit` command.

Oh! And it appears you have a **file** called `Adding`.  Note that the `git status` command ends with

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Adding
```

This happens when you ask Git to track a directory (such as when you did `git init .`).  From then on Git monitors changes in the specified location.  The above is saying that "I see that you have added a file called Adding.  I don't know much more about it (it is untracked)."   Once you add it, Git starts tracking changes (can tell you **what** has changed with it over time).